# Entity framework 6 transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I need to insert  new rows in two of my tables first table's auto generated id field is one of the field of second table .currently I'm using transaction  for inserting data. My current code is given below

```
        using (var context = new ApplicationDatabaseEntities())
        {
            using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                   foreach (var item in itemList)
                   {
                    context.MyFirstEntity.Add(item);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    mySecondEntity.MyFirstEntityId = item.Id;
                    context.MySecondEntity.Add(mySecondEntity.MyFirstEntityId );
                    context.SaveChanges();

                   }
                  transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);

                }
            }
        }
```

The above code is working fine .my question is, is this the correct way? I mean if I have 1000 or 2000 items for insertion does my current code affect the performance

Comment: You should wrap your transaction in a `using` statement.

Comment: Say you have 1000 items for insertion; 999 occur successfully, the 1000 fails... do you want to roll back all of them or just the last 1 that failed? (your code will do that). I suspect that it should leave the 999 successes and only rollback the failed 1 transaction. Therefore I guess you actually want your foreach to be put inbetween the two using statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code can be improved with implicit transaction:

```
foreach (var item in itemList)
{
    context.MyFirstEntity.Add(item);
    mySecondEntity.MyFirstEntity = item;
    context.MySecondEntity.Add(mySecondEntity);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Note: instead of id I've used navigation property.

Comment: I don't need entire item only just one field value

Comment: You are assigning `MyFirstEntityId` to `item.Id`, this code will do the same after `SaveChanges()` is called.

Comment: When you call SaveChanges everything is wrapped in one transaction... using one transaction for say 1000  items inserted... 999 successfully, the last 1 fails... so your SaveChanges outside of the loop would cause all 1000 to rollback? euch.

Comment: This code will create only one transaction (called implicit transaction) in SaveChanges. So either all of entities would be inserted, or none of them.

Comment: Oh yeah and it will use whatever the data providers default isolation level is, e.g. SQL Server is READ COMMITTED

Comment: Actually, this code can be improved performance-wise if transaction for all entities is not important. You can call SaveChanges let's say for each 200 items.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your transaction in a `using` statement and rollback when an exception is thrown.

```
using (DbContextTransaction transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
   try
   {
      foreach (var item in itemList)
      {
         context.MyFirstEntity.Add(item);
         mySecondEntity.MyFirstEntity = item;
         context.MySecondEntity.Add(mySecondEntity);
      }

      transaction.Commit();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      transaction.Rollback();
   } 
}
```

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If the whole batch has to be transactional then you have no other way as do in one big transaction. If transaction has to be guaranteed for tupples only then if the time of transaction is big enough you may face some locks. Then you can just do transaction in the loop for each tupple.

Also you can do what you are doing in one go without explicit transaction. You can `SaveChanges` after the loop and it will be transactional:

```
foreach (var item in itemList)
{
    context.MyFirstEntity.Add(item);
    mySecondEntity.MyFirstEntity = item;
    context.MySecondEntity.Add(mySecondEntity);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```